# How to include custom taxonomies to Woo products CSV export / import?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce, export

Can't find what's wrong with my code. I made custom taxonomies for products and trying to include them to WC default import / export. The first part works fine, new fields are exposed in export configurator. But the next function make exporter freeze with rolling spinner.

```
/* COLUMN ***************/
function add_export_columns( $columns ) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        $columns['publisher'] = 'Publisher';
        return $columns;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_column_names', 'add_export_columns' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_default_columns', 'add_export_columns' );

/* EXPORT ***************/
function add_export_data_publishers( $publisher, $product ) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        $publisher = $product->get_the_terms('publisher', true);
        return $publisher;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_publisher', 'add_export_data_publishers', 10, 2 );
```

I also tried to change $product to $post ( `$publisher = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'publisher', true);` ) — in that case export goes fine, I got my CSV, but Publisher column contains only zeroes.
Please help to find my mistake.

Comment: So looking at the documentation for `get_the_terms()` requires passing the ID or post object so you might need to change `$publisher = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'publisher', true);` to `$publisher = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'publisher', true);` I don't see a method `get_the_terms` for Class WC_Product https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html This resource might also be helpful for what you can retrieve from the $product object https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/

Comment: I just realised that get_the_terms returns array. Var_dump result: `array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#15952 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(20) ["name"]=> string(10) "Eksmo" ["slug"]=> string(5) "eksmo" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(20) ["taxonomy"]=> string(9) "publisher" … …}`. I modified my function ```function add_export_data_publishers() {
 if (is_admin()) {
  $publisher_arr = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'publisher');
  $publisher = $publisher_arr->name;
  return $publisher;
 }
}```, still it returns nothing in exported CSV column Publisher.